# Why does conductivity of electrolyte solutions peak at high concentrations?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, conductivity

I've recently done a lab about conductivity of brine over time (high concentration salt water). I passed current through salt water and measured the current over time.

The graphs I got showed that current through the solution rose to a peak before falling, and it looks almost like the positive x-value half of a quadratic function. I understand it falls because resistance increases with the progress of the redox reaction, but what causes the peak at the top?